# How to fetch parameters from POST call in python web service

Tags: php, android, python

I am a python developer who is completely new to web development. I wish to develop a web service in python which authenticates user and returns a token.

I was able to do that using PHP (thanks to all the blogs available online). But soon realized that I want to do that in python.

Where I am stuck is that-

- I don't understand how to fetch the parameters from POST request, like I was fetching in PHP (see code).
- How to return a string or code (in PHP it's echo, should I user *return*?)

  ```
  // include db connect class
  require_once('veggieking_connect.php');

  // connecting to db
  $db = new VEGGIEKING_CONNECT();

  // set mysql_query for utf8
  mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");

  $emp_id = $_POST["mEmpID"];
  $emp_pwd = $_POST["mPassword"];

  $result = mysql_query("select * from empdata where emp_id like '$emp_id' and emp_pwd like '$emp_pwd'") or die(mysql_error());                

  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          echo $row['emp_email'];
      }
  }
  else {
   echo "Fail";
  }

  ?>
  ```

Just like in PHP, emp_id and emp_pwd are fetched, how to do that in python web serice when I call using the same POST request in android.

I understand it's a simple question, but I can't find any good python web services examples which explains what's happening in the code. If you are aware of where I can learn these, please share the url's also, it would be really helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: for python web development you can try [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), for Restful API service [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your php code i understand bit that you want to retrieve and then fetch data in database. For this purpose in python use "psycopg2" module.

[psycopg2 python Documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html)

Using this Module you can do any operations related to database from python code.
I hope this will help you.